# converting char array to int using c++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, int

Can anyone explain me how this code results `16843009`? How it works?

As I saw in my tests, `(int *)&x` results `0x61ff1b` and as I know that is the address of the first element in the array. and how the result of `*(int *)&x` is `16843009`? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char x[5] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    cout << *(int *)&x;

   return 0;;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ps: try printing it as hex value instead

Comment: @JVApen I just wanted to understand how it works.

Comment: I read that? Why? The first one trying to use this in my code will have to defend herself/himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we write 16843009 as binary we get `1000000010000000100000001`.  Padding that with extra zeros we get: `00000001000000010000000100000001`. Every 8 bits (which is a char) has a value of `00000001`, which is `1`.

`&x` is a pointer to an array of char (Specifically a `char(*)[5]`). This is reinterpreted as a pointer to int. On your system, `int` is probably 4 bytes, and all four of those bytes are seperately set to 1, which means you get an int where every 8 bits are set to 1.